# Trace raspberry pi booting process

Tags: boot

I want to trace the raspberry pi booting process . I want to see in which file , in which function we are at a particular time and what that function is doing .
Can anybody tell me the best way through which i can do this ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You may

Use `qemu` to emulate raspbian.The process is documented in this [link](http://xecdesign.com/qemu-emulating-raspberry-pi-the-easy-way/)

```
$ mkdir ~/rpi_emu
$ cd ~/rpi_emu
$ wget http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian_latest -0 -O 2014-01-07-wheezy-raspbian.zip
$ unzip 2014-01-07-wheezy-raspbian.zip -d .
$ rm 2014-01-07-wheezy-raspbian.zip
$ wget http://xecdesign.com/downloads/linux-qemu/kernel-qemu
$ qemu-system-arm -kernel kernel-qemu -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -M versatilepb -no-reboot -serial stdio -append "root=/dev/sda2 panic=1 rootfstype=ext4 rw init=/bin/bash" -hda 2014-01-07-wheezy-raspbian.img
```

This does not work under some windows managers. I have tried `i3wm`, `awesome` and `GNOME Shell`. Only `GNOME Shell` worked and the other two halted when I tried to focus my mouse to the guest OS.

If you successfully login to Raspbian, change the file `/etc/ld.so.preload` but not `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcofi_rpi.so`. As far as I know, this file contains only one line, put a `#` in front of it. Save and shutdown the Raspbian.

The second time boot it with

```
$ qemu-system-arm -s -S -kernel kernel-qemu -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -M versatilepb -no-reboot -serial stdio -append "root=/dev/sda2 panic=1 rootfstype=ext4 rw" -hda 2014-01-07-wheezy-raspbian.img
```

Then open another terminal, run

```
$ gdb-multiarch
```

`qemu` will wait for a gdb connection to start, so

```
$ gdb-multiarch
(gdb) set architecture arm
(gdb) target remote localhost:1234
(gdb) si            # to debug step by step
(gdb) x/i <address> # to disassemble code
```

Answer (score -1):

Install the `bootlogd` package using :

`apt-get install bootlogd`

It logs the boot process in `/var/log/boot`